# After selecting datalist item , the dropdown remains. How can i make sure it disappears?

Tags: javascript, datalist

```
<input class="c-search__textbox c-form__textbox"  id="top-query" list="top-json-datalist" onkeyup="suggest(this)" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Type something . . .">

<datalist id="top-json-datalist"></datalist>

function suggest(elem) { 

if(elem.id == "query") {
    document.getElementById("query").disabled = false;
    var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
    var input = document.getElementById('query');
} else if (elem.id == "top-query") { 
    document.getElementById("top-query").disabled = false;
    var dataList = document.getElementById('top-json-datalist');
    var input = document.getElementById('top-query');
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Handle state changes for the request.
request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var jsonOptions = data.hits;
        dataList.innerHTML = '';
        jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = item["query"];
            dataList.appendChild(option);
        });
    } 
  }
};

request.open('GET','https://api.lite.s4p.jp/v1/suggest&query='+input.value,true);
request.send();
```

As you can see I am able to load datalist items from ajax call.
I am able to see the items in the dropdown list. However, the problem is that when the item is selected, the drop-down still remains.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering whether you are doing something in your suggest function that is causing a problem, does it work if you remove onkeyup="suggest(this)"?

The other thing is that support for datalist seems [quite buggy according to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist). Have you tried in other browsers?

Sorry, would have just commented but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: It wouldn't work if I removed `onkeyup="suggest(this)"` 
It works fine on firefox but doesn't work on Safari because of support issue.
I think I will avoid using datalist element :-) Thanks!

Comment: @omrajpurohit You’re welcome.if you found my answer helpful would you mind accepting it please, thanks.